# How can I reload only div content in html:form action? Struts 1.3

Tags: java, struts, reload, tiles

I'm developing a web application using Struts 1.3.10, Tiles and Hibernate.

The login form is inside body tile, and I need to reload only body content when login button is submit.
This is the form:

```
login.jsp 
<div class="login">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <html:form action="/loginAction" >
        <div><p>User</p> <html:text property="userName" /></div>
        <div><p>Password</p> <html:password property="password" /></div>
        <div><html:submit value="Login"/></div>
    </html:form>
</div>
```

And this is the loginAction:

```
loginAction.java
 @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {

        loginForm lForm = (loginForm) form;
        String userName = lForm.getUserName();
        String password = lForm.getPassword();

        Boolean ack = Login.checkCredentials(userName, password);
        if(ack){
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("SessionLogin", "true");
        }else{ 
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I'm trying to return null because i don't need to forward to another page, I only want to reload div content (through javascript). But the result of this action is white page.

Do you know how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Have you looked into using jquery to submit the data as an ajax request?

Comment: yes! I have tried but html:form definiton needs to be associated to an action, I don't know how to avoid this, do you know?

Comment: You could use an <html:button onclick="javascript:callMyMethodToSubmitAjax()" value="Submit"/>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the code below to call a javascript method that will submit an ajax request.

```
<html:button onclick="javascript:callMyMethodToSubmitAjax()" value="Submit"/>
```

The javascript would look something like what is below

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function callMyMethodToSubmitAjax() {

    var $form = $('#strutsFormHtmlId'); // set your form ID

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: $form.attr('action'),
        data: $form.serialize(), 
        success: function (msg) { 
            alert("success");
        },
        error: function (msg) {
           alert("error");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It's not working enough, I mean I get correctly the form data in javascript but no alert is displayed after ajax call, seems that some operation is not working. Could you send me an example of struts-config and the action?

Comment: Do you see the request being sent or do you see the request hitting the controller?  You could use firebug to see if the request is being sent and also to see if there are javascript errors.

Comment: one aditional question, if I want to pass a session variable through the method, how can i do it?

Comment: If it is in the session there will be no need to pass it from the page to the controller.  You can use request.getSession().getAttribute("attribute_name");

Comment: If you want to pass the session variable to the javascript function just use expression ${SessionLogin} in your jsp. This only works since jsp 2